Including author name in ibid citations
I would like to have multiple citations in the same page listed as ibid., but also include the author name.
Here's an MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Cite1: \citep{key} \newline
Cite2: \citep{key}

\end{document}

The default settings in authoryear-ibid only includes (ibid.) - I would like to have Author (ibid.).

"Ibid." is short for "Ibidem", which is Latin for "in the same place". Please clarify your use case for wanting to clog a citation call-out with redundant information (here: the author name).

You get "Author (ibid.)" if you use \textcite/\citet, because for textual citations the author name is always part of the surrounding sentence. Normally \textcite/\citet produces citations of the form "Author (year)". For parenthetical citations it appears to me to be more logical not to include the author if it can be dropped because there is no such expectation.

@moewe \citet does what I want, thanks! :) if you could write it as an answer, I could accept it :)

Use \textcite (or \citet in natbib compatibility mode) for narrative/textual citations in which the name forms part of the sentence. Then you get "Author (ibid.)" for ibidem citations.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
lorem \citep{sigfridsson}

ipsum \citep{sigfridsson}

dolor \textcite{sigfridsson}

sit \citet{sigfridsson}

consectur \textcite{worman}
\end{document}


